# Compute and Save time frame to a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a beginner and I am looking for some JavaScript ( or any web language) simple samples to compute time.

I want to display a text for 60 seconds and want to fade away the text after the time has elapsed.

I want to record a start time. And at the end, when the text starts showing up and dissapears.

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us some code, so we know you tried instead of asking somebody to write it for you.

Comment: SO Is not a coding service. If you want code, pay someone to do it. We can help you debug any issues you're having, but we aren't here to do work for you.

Comment: Google for "javascript timer".

Answer (score 1):

OK - I agree with the commenters that this isn't the place. But you can use jQuery like so: http://jsfiddle.net/tbgs901r/

```
$(function() {
    var timeoutinms = 1000;    
    setInterval(function(){ 
        $('.flashMe').toggle(); 
    }, timeoutinms);
});
```

Be sure to include jQuery in your page.

EDIT: I included a VanillaJS ( Google it ) implementation since it's friday :)
http://jsfiddle.net/tbgs901r/1/

```
setInterval(function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('flashMeVanillaJS');
    el.style.visibility = el.style.visibility === 'visible' ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
}, 1500);
```